# Laravel 5 Simple Comparison Fails

Tags: php, laravel-5

This should be simple but for some reason code in my `if` block is executing despite the fact that it resolves to `false` and it's making me very unhappy... My user_id in this case is `2`.

```
$note = Notification::where("user_id",Auth::user()->id)->first();
$wall = $note->pluck('wall');
if($wall != 0)
{
//This code is executing!
}
else{
    array_push($data,"Your First Time!");   
    //This code is not!
}
```

As you can see, my $wall should be zero so I don't understand why `$wall != 0` runs.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure `$wall` is indeed `0`? Try `var_dump($wall);` before your `if( ..) {..`

Comment: I don't think you need to use pluck. You are already retrieving a model by using ->first(). Simply do $note->wall

Comment: @Darren Thanks, it gave me `string(3) "130"` so for some reason it's reading from the wrong `user_id`... why would that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove pluck

```
$note = Notification::where("user_id",Auth::user()->id)->first();
$wall = $note->wall; //This changed
if($wall != 0)
{
//This code is executing!
}
else{
    array_push($data,"Your First Time!");   
    //This code is not!
}
```